# Select Menu not updating when line charts are filtered

Tags: d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

please see this Pen
https://codepen.io/rdavi10471a2/project/editor/XwGGYo

clicking on any of the charts will filter the data but the filters are not reflected in the select menus

using the select menus themselves will filter the charts so it is unclear why the select menu UI does not update on chart filter.

choosing a year in the left most chart will cause the Year dropdown to change but selecting a department from the right most chart does not filter the department dropdown nor does selecting a single branch from the center chart filter the branch drop down.

menus are defined like this

```
 branchdd
    .dimension(branchDimension)
    .group(branchDimension.group())
      .multiple(true)
     .numberVisible(5)
     .title(kv => kv.key)  
   .controlsUseVisibility(true)

deptdd
    .dimension(deptDimension)
    .group(deptDimension.group())
      .multiple(true)
     .title(kv => kv.key)  
   .controlsUseVisibility(true)
perioddd
    .dimension(dateDimension3)
    .group(dateDimension3.group())
      .multiple(true)
     .title(kv => kv.key)  
   .controlsUseVisibility(true)
```

sample chart definition

```
salesbybranch
    .width(300)
    .height(400)
   // .x(d3.scaleLinear().domain([6,20]))
    .elasticX(true)
    .dimension(branchDimension)
    .group(salesbranch)
    .fixedBarHeight(10)
    .title(function(d) { return "Value: " +d.key+" " + dollarformat(d.value); })
    .renderTitle(true)

 salesbybranch.xAxis().ticks(5).tickFormat(d3.formatPrefix(".2", 1e6)) 
salesbybranch.renderlet(function (chart) {
 salesbybranch.xAxis().ticks(5).tickFormat(d3.formatPrefix(".2", 1e6)) 
})
```

[image: screenshot to show issue]

Comment: [A group does not observe its own dimension's filters](https://github.com/crossfilter/crossfilter/wiki/Crossfilter-Gotchas#a-group-does-not-observe-its-dimensions-filters) ?

Comment: Gordon, I assume that is what I am seeing. when i used separate dimensions for the drop downs and the charts the charts would filter the dropdowns but only show the elements that were selected in the charts.. not quite the two way behavior I was expecting. so I have moved on to not use the dropdowns and  show the filters (not formatted very well) in a text box under the chart.

Comment: Got it. I think you're looking for something like this feature: https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/pull/682 only generalized for any charts (as I commented should be done there). I started on an implementation but never found time to complete it. It would be a natural generalization of how dc.js charts work.

Comment: Gordon, please check out the PEN from above. It is a little bit of a cludge but I think i can get where I want to go with dropdowns if the dropdowns on change uses code like this       `bfilter = []
  bfilter[0] = ["branch-01","branch-02"] 
  salesbybranch.filter(bfilter)
  yfilter = []
  yfilter[0] = ["2016","2017"] 
  salesbyyear.filter(yfilter)
  
  dfilter = []
  dfilter[0] = ["New Truck","Used Truck"] 
  salesbydept.filter(dfilter) `                                                                                     In the on change handlers for the multi-select

Comment: That seems like a reasonable workaround to me. Kind of a bummer that you had to drop `dc.selectMenu` to get this to work; I think you could do sort of the same thing using `selectMenu` and putting the menu and chart both on the same dimension as you originally had.

Comment: https://codepen.io/rdavi10471a2/project/editor/XwGGYo shows where I ended up abandoning synchrnization and allowing the drop down to add/remove branches including select/deselct all. I would love to have the two way communication work but I just couldn't get it to handle all the cases. So by disabling the click on the chart the dropdown is always in control.

Answer (score 0):

forgive the forEach on a single element but putting this in document ready after the dc.renderAll() so that it gets executed after the charts are added works (needs better formatting but it shows the user what the filters are.
would be better to move to a collapsible single div somewhere on the page as well

```
    dc.chartRegistry.list().forEach( function(e){
      //e.on('filtered', refreshTable);
      ['filter'].forEach( function(n) {
        this.root().append('div')
          .classed(n, true)
          //.attr('id', `${this.anchorName()}-${n}`)

      }, e);

      ['reset'].forEach( function(n) {
        this.root().append('a')
          .classed(n, true)
          .attr('id', `${this.anchorName()}-${n}`)
          .text(n === 'reset' ? 'Clear Filters' : '')
          .on('click', function() {
              console.log(e)
            e.replaceFilter(null);
            dc.redrawAll();
            console.log(`clicked ${n} div`);
          });
      }, e);
});

  $('.reset').hide();
  $('.filter').css("background-color","yellow")
  $('.filter').css("overflow","scroll")
  $('.filter').css("max-height","50px")
})
```

as always could use some cleanup..

[image: but here is what it looks like]

Comment: I am unclear how this relates to the question - seems to answer a different question?

Comment: sorry for the confusion. that is my free *project* on pen so I kept editing it  this was to show how I attempted to abandon the dc.selects all together but come up with a way to show what was filtered and how to clear all the filters before I found out that DC supports this automatically if you put the right divs in the html .